# Unable to control keyboard backlight on ubuntu for input: eSport Arena eSport keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard, backlight

Im unable to control the keyboard light for this keyboard.
Its turned off after sleep.

Dissasembled the keyboard there are 2x wtu602 chips in there and thats all

I tried:

```
xset led [1-32]
```

dmesg entry:

```
[33339.121199] usb 2-1.8.5: reset full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[33339.230948] input: eSport Arena eSport Arena Penta Keys as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.8/2-1.8.5/2-1.8.5:1.0/0003:2EA8:2123.0008/input/input25
[33339.289582] hid-generic 0003:2EA8:2123.0008: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [eSport Arena eSport Arena Penta Keys] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.8.5/input0
[33339.291560] input: eSport Arena eSport Arena Penta Keys as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.8/2-1.8.5/2-1.8.5:1.1/0003:2EA8:2123.0009/input/input26
[33339.349400] hid-generic 0003:2EA8:2123.0009: input,hiddev2,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [eSport Arena eSport Arena Penta Keys] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.8.5/input1
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 2ea8:2123
```

Comment: Did you try unplugging the USB connection and plugging it back in?

Comment: Another thing, did you try: `sudo sensors-detect`? This helps for some built-in keyboards.

Comment: Tried both, unplugging and sensors-detect no luck.
Dissasembled the keyboard there are 2x wtu602 chips in there and thats all